# htmlagility insert into line number

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have a question about htmlagilitypack.

How can I insert into specific line or lineposition (not node)? If I have HtmlParseError at line 100 (missing opening tag ), how can I insert this missing tag into that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, you can't.

You'll have to reload the file with a standard text stream (StreamReader say), and fix it directly in the raw text, using the line & column position.